# Spring Boot: Response timestamp is advance 1 hour

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Supposed I am saving the data with this code

```
@Override
public Footer insert(Userto userDto) {
    User user = modelMapper.map(userDto, User.class);

    return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
}
```

and it is working fine and im getting the result as follows

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "name test",
    "age": "33",
    "created_at": "2019-12-10T16:53:40",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-10T16:53:40",
}
```

However the **created_at** and **updated_at** is 1 hour advance

but when I look at the database the result is fine and it is not advance with 1 hour the result should be

```
    "created_at": "2019-12-10T15:53:40",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-10T15:53:40",
```

UserDto

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class UserDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String age;

}
```

and this is my created at and updated at on user entity

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")
private LocalDateTime created_at;

@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")
private LocalDateTime updated_at;
```

Comment: Is database server and application server on same timezone?

Comment: the timestamp on the database is inserted correctly but return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user); this returns the timestamp but + 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using jpa property

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = Asia/Tokyo
```